# Click Once Install Problem With System.Data.SqlServerCe?

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation, clickonce, gac

Stack-O

I have a click once application that has been deployed, and I tried installing it on a coworker's computer and got the following error:

> Unable to install or run the
>   application.  The application requires
>   that assembly System.Data.SqlServerCe
>   version 3.5.1.0 be installed in the
>   Global Assembly Cash (GAC) first.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can install it or make sure you have all the dll's with your distrubution: [How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact Edition Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you have referenced System.Data.SqlServerCe in your application then make sure that in "Application files" section of the publish window, set the "Publish Status" of this dll file as "Include" instead of prerequisite. This should get you rid of this problem.